# Convert 987,654,321.09 format string into 987,654,321.09 number format in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I trying to convert a string 987,654,321.09 into a number with the same format
I am using a case in my select statement as follows:

```
select 
case when NUMBER_FORMAT is null or NUMBER_FORMAT = 0 
then
to_number ('987,654,321.09', '999,999,999.99')
else
NUMBER_FORMAT end as numberFormat
from agileuser;
```

This query returns the format as 987654321.09.

Does anybody knows how can this can be returned as 987,654,321.09 in number datatype.

Comment: a format mask is for a string (adding commas to make it readable, etc).  The to_number will return a number.

Comment: The number 1000 does not have a comma in it (1,000), nor does it have a decimal point (1000.00, or 1,000.00). The number 1000 is just a number, just like 999. Commas and decimal points (and even the sign, + or -) only exist in the string representation of a number. Try to get away from everything else you do and reflect for ten minutes about this. Then realize that the same thing is true about dates: A date is just a date (and time-of-day, in Oracle), there are no two different "date" values for it. There may be 22 different string representations, and the date is still just one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I did the following and it works:

```
select 
case when to_char(to_number(NUMBER_FORMAT), '999,999,999.00') is null or to_char(to_number(NUMBER_FORMAT), '999,999,999.00') = 0 
then
to_char(to_number('987654321.09'), '999,999,999.00')
else
to_char(to_number(NUMBER_FORMAT), '999,999,999.00') end as numberFormat
from agileuser
```